# Applying UK Visit Visa Application from AU

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, australia

I am a Bangladeshi Citizen. I came to Australia on visit visa (600) on August. I want to know if I can apply for a UK visitor visa from Australia.

The problem is I don't have any documents with me now, since I live in Bangladesh. I may not be able to show Bank Statements. In this case, is it possible for my sister in Australia to sponsor me or my friend in the UK to sponsor me (to bear my expense in the UK)? How likely am I to get a visa this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply, but your application is virtually certain to be refused unless you can demonstrate a credible reason for wanting to visit and that you have:

- strong ties to your home country that would compel you to leave at the end of the visit (which seems unlikely, since you’re already in Australia on a visit visa) and
- sufficient funds for the trip (which would require 6 months’ bank statements from you, irrespective of whether you have a sponsor) that are genuinely available to you

https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules